# union tables in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I am little low with sql, So this is something new to me.

I am selecting data from two tables and doing their union

```
declare @randomlinkscards table
    (cardTitleinfo nvarchar(max),
    cardIdinfo bigint
    )
    declare @randomlinksvideos table
    (
    videotitle nvarchar(max),
    videoid bigint
    )
    insert into @randomlinkscards(cardTitleinfo,cardIdinfo) select top 1 cardTable.cardTitle,cardTable.CardId from cardTable where is_active='True' order by newid()
    insert into @randomlinksvideos(videotitle,videoid) select top 1 videos.title,videos.video_id from videos where is_active='True' order by newid()
    select videotitle,videoid from @randomlinksvideos union all select * from @randomlinkscards
```

As it provides me the output-

## [image]

From the image you can see that It is returning two rows.

**One row of video table**

**One row of cardTable**

However data is coming as I wanted it to be , but managing it with two rows is the problem that persists.

I want to manage this all data in one row. How do I attempt to get this data in one row

Comment: show your expected output

Comment: @Ganesh_Devlekar, My expected output is a row of these two rows

Comment: I think You want two rows separately....??  then just remove union all `select videotitle,videoid from @randomlinksvideos; select * from @randomlinkscards;`

Comment: @Ganesh_Devlekar, But that shows result from two different tables, I wanted to have union with one row

Comment: it will be better to some more rows with expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a solution to your problem but if you want show data from two table then you should have a common columns between them and u can get the result through join.

```
SELECT (SELECT videotitle
        FROM   @randomlinksvideos)videotitle,
       (SELECT videoid
        FROM   @randomlinksvideos)videoid,
       (SELECT cardTitleinfo
        FROM   @randomlinkscards) cardTitleinfo,
       (SELECT cardIdinfo
        FROM   @randomlinkscards) cardIdinfo
```